# progress fill on button click

Tags: java, android, button, android-progressbar

I am looking to create a progress bar that shows on top of the button on click. Like this:
http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/

Any idea how this could be done? Is their any existing library?

Comment: ProgressBar class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html  (You would need to tweak to implement it into a button im sure)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712536/positioning-a-progress-bar-behind-a-button

Here is a duplicate question

Comment: ...with an accepted answer. You should at least explain what you have tried why it doesn't work for you.